# Pandas Dataframe to Sqlite - Bindings Issue

Tags: python, sqlite, dataframe

I know this is an easy topic with several threads, but i couldn't find the solution.

What i have is a txt file i read into a array and transform it to a Dataframe.
After that i'll transform single columns such that it is a date / number. I am sure there is a more efficient way to construct what i am looking for but it worked for me.

Ill end up with a dataframe that looks like that:

```
    PSVLD Market Date PSVLD Ticker PSVLD Tenor Date  PSVLD Percent of Spot  \
1         2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   50.0   
2         2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   60.0   
3         2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   70.0   
4         2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   75.0   
5         2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   80.0   
6         2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   85.0   
7         2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   90.0   
8         2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   92.5   
9         2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   95.0   
10        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   97.5   

    PSVLD Vol  
1    34.96749  
2    34.36383  
3    32.58459  
4    30.53958  
5    28.30699  
6    24.74774  
7    20.07822  
8    17.38867  
9    14.58027  
10   11.84767
```

And now i want to insert this data into a database. I created a new table and tried to execute this dataframe into my file but it does not work.

```
con = sq3.connect('my_db.db')

query = 'CREATE TABLE ImpliedVola (Date date, Ticker varchar(50), Tenor varchar(10),Strike real, IV real)' 
con.execute(query)
con.commit()
con.executemany('INSERT INTO ImpliedVola VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', df)
```

But unfortunatly it says something about 17 bindings. Do you have an idea what i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 17 supplied.
```

Comment: Nevertheless, someone knows what i did wrong here? because i could replace the query with updater or insert if i get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the native Pandas [DataFrame.to_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method.

Demo:

```
In [41]: import sqlite3

In [42]: con = sqlite3.connect('d:/temp/df.sqlite')

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
  PSVLD Market Date PSVLD Ticker PSVLD Tenor Date  PSVLD Percent of Spot  PSVLD Vol
0        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   50.0   34.96749
1        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   60.0   34.36383
2        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   70.0   32.58459
3        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   75.0   30.53958
4        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   80.0   28.30699
5        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   85.0   24.74774
6        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   90.0   20.07822
7        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   92.5   17.38867
8        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   95.0   14.58027
9        2017-02-03      .MSCIEA               1M                   97.5   11.84767

In [44]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_')).to_sql('ImpliedVola', con, if_exists='replace')
```

Result:

```
D:\temp>sqlite3 df.sqlite
SQLite version 3.10.1 2016-01-13 21:41:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> select * from ImpliedVola;
index       PSVLD_Market_Date    PSVLD_Ticker  PSVLD_Tenor_Date  PSVLD_Percent_of_Spot  PSVLD_Vol
----------  -------------------  ------------  ----------------  ---------------------  ----------
0           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                50.0                   34.96749
1           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                60.0                   34.36383
2           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                70.0                   32.58459
3           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                75.0                   30.53958
4           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                80.0                   28.30699
5           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                85.0                   24.74774
6           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                90.0                   20.07822
7           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                92.5                   17.38867
8           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                95.0                   14.58027
9           2017-02-03 00:00:00  .MSCIEA       1M                97.5                   11.84767
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. this works but to_sql() replaces all previous data in the table. since i want to add data day by day i am not sure how to work around that.

Comment: @StefanMüller, simply use `if_exists='append'`

Comment: another question, 
Can i also declare some primary keys and update the existing values?
Like UPDATE in sql?

Comment: @StefanMüller, you would have to do it manually. There is no native Pandas method for that (yet)

Comment: Hi MaxU,

you think i can tackle the problem with something like this?

`for index,row in df.iterrows():   con.execute('INSERT INTO ImpVol_Data (Date, Ticker, Tenor,Strike,IV) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IV = ?',[row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[4]])`

Comment: @StefanMüller, i think you should open a new question